# How to pass the starting index of a two dimensional subarray in c?

Tags: c, for-loop, multidimensional-array, function-declaration

I want to pass the 2-D subarray in C as we can pass the 1-D subarray:

I had passed the 1-D subarray as follows:

**Code**

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print_array(int *arr, int len)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    int size = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(int);
    print_array(&arr[2], size - 2);
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
3 4 5
```

But how can I do the same for a two dimensional array?
I have a 2-D array as follows:

```
int arr[6][6] = {
        {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6},
        {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7},
        {3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8},
        {4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9},
        {5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10},
        {6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11}};
```

I want to pass the index of the `arr[1][1]` element so that I can print the sub 2-D array:

```
3 4 5 6 7
4 5 6 7 8
5 6 7 8 9
6 7 8 9 10
7 8 9 10 11
```

I tried it as follows, but it didn't worked:

**Code**

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print_array(int row, int column, int (*arr)[column])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < column; j++)
        {
            printf("%d ", arr[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    int arr[6][6] = {
        {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6},
        {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7},
        {3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8},
        {4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9},
        {5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10},
        {6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11}};

    print_array(5, 5, &arr[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
2 3 4 5 6 
7 3 4 5 6 
7 8 4 5 6 
7 8 9 5 6 
7 8 9 10 6
```

I don't know how this output is generated also please tell me how can I achieve my goal by passing the address.

**Note:** I had passed `&arr[1]` because passing `&arr[1][1]` says `incompatible pointer type for the function argument`.

I know we can do it in other ways but, how can I pass the subarray as we can do it in 1-D array?

And if it is not possible in any way then please tell me what is the main reason behind it as the method worked for 1-D array but not for 2-D array.

Because I thought that passing `arr` is doing the same (i.e. accessing its members as `arr[0][0]` `arr[1][0]` and so on. So why not to pass the starting index of a subarray to get the entire subarray easily.

Comment: What you are saying is logically not possible. You can not cut a 2D sub-array like this. Just think. Even if you are able to pass some starting index, you will start from there and then when you will change the row, you will end up behind the starting index.  You can't cut columns like this.

Comment: You can instead pass the original dimensions and the starting index. Then simply use an `if` condition while printing for those indices which are ahead of the starting index.

Answer (score 2):

One way to achieve this is by passing the original dimensions of `arr` and the starting indices, `srow` and `scol` and then starting the loops at these indices.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print_array(int row, int column, int srow, int scol, int (*arr)[column])
{
    for (int i = srow; i < row; i++)
    {
        for (int j = scol; j < column; j++)
        {
            printf("%d ", arr[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    int arr[6][6] = {
        {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6},
        {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7},
        {3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8},
        {4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9},
        {5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10},
        {6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11}};

    print_array(6, 6, 1, 1, arr);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a two dimensional array like this

```
enum { M = 6, N = 6 };
int arr[M][N] = 
{
    { 1, 2, 3, 4,  5,  6 },
    { 2, 3, 4, 5,  6,  7 },
    { 3, 4, 5, 6,  7,  8 },
    { 4, 5, 6, 7,  8,  9 },
    { 5, 6, 7, 8,  9, 10 },
    { 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11 }
};
```

and want to output it starting from the row position `pos` where `pos` is some value less than `M` then you can pass it to a function like the expression

```
arr + pos
```

You can not change the number of elements in a row of the array. So the function parameter that specifies the sub-array must look like

```
int ( *arr )[columns]
```

where `columns` specifies the actual number of columns in the original array.

What you also need to pass to the function is the starting number of column from which you are going to output a sub-array.

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print_array( size_t rows, size_t columns, size_t pos, int ( *arr )[columns] )
{
    if ( pos < columns )
    {
        for ( size_t i = 0; i < rows; i++ )
        {
            for ( size_t j = pos; j < columns; j++ )
            {
                printf( "%2d ", arr[i][j] );
            }
            putchar( '\n' );
        }
    }
}

int main(void) 
{
    enum { M = 6, N = 6 };
    int arr[M][N] = 
    {
        { 1, 2, 3, 4,  5,  6 },
        { 2, 3, 4, 5,  6,  7 },
        { 3, 4, 5, 6,  7,  8 },
        { 4, 5, 6, 7,  8,  9 },
        { 5, 6, 7, 8,  9, 10 },
        { 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11 }
    };
    
    for ( size_t pos = 1; pos < M; ++ pos )
    {
        print_array( M - pos, N, pos, arr + pos );
        putchar( '\n' );
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
 3  4  5  6  7 
 4  5  6  7  8 
 5  6  7  8  9 
 6  7  8  9 10 
 7  8  9 10 11 

 5  6  7  8 
 6  7  8  9 
 7  8  9 10 
 8  9 10 11 

 7  8  9 
 8  9 10 
 9 10 11 

 9 10 
10 11 

11
```

Pay attention to that it is not necessary that starting address of row and starting address of column must be equal to each other. For example you can call the function like

```
print_array( M - 3, N, 1, arr + 3 );
```

Answer (score -2):

I would recommend using nested `std::array` or `std::vector`. If your array size is not known during runtime, use vector. If your array size is known, use std::array

```
#include <array>
using nested_int_array = std::array<std::array<int, 6> >, 6>; //6 = size of array

void printsubarray(int begin_row, int begin_column, const nested_int_array& ar)
{
   for (int r = begin_row; r < ar.size(); r++)
   {
      for (int c = begin_column; c < ar[0].size(); c++)
      {
           printf("%i ", ar[r][c]);
      }
      printf("\n");
   }
}
```

Comment: The question is tagged C, not C++. There is `std::array` or `std::vector` in C.

Comment: It's C, not C++